# BigQuery, FIRST_VALUE, and null

Tags: google-bigquery

In the following example, I would have expected the results

```
Row    a    b    f0_     
1    1    1    3     
2    1    2    3     
3    1    3    5     
4    1    4    5     
5    1    5    null
```

because, in general, aggregates tend to ignore nulls.  If `FIRST_VALUE` doesn't ignore nulls, what value does it have over using `LEAD`

Example:

```
select a, b, first_value(c) over (partition by a order by b asc rows BETWEEN 1 following AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
from 
(select 1 as a, 1 as b, 1 as c),
(select 1 as a, 2 as b, null as c),
(select 1 as a, 3 as b, 3 as c),
(select 1 as a, 4 as b, null as c),
(select 1 as a, 5 as b, 5 as c),
```

gives

```
Row    a    b    f0_     
1    1    1    null     
2    1    2    3     
3    1    3    null     
4    1    4    5     
5    1    5    5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the first not null value from a column of values in Big Query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788958/how-to-get-the-first-not-null-value-from-a-column-of-values-in-big-query)

Answer (score 1):

> I would have expected the results

Below trick gives expected (in your question) result

```
SELECT
  a, b, 
  MAX(c) OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY grp ASC RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a, b, c, 
    COUNT(c) OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b ASC rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) grp
  FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS a, 1 AS b, 1 AS c),
    (SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b, NULL AS c),
    (SELECT 1 AS a, 3 AS b, 3 AS c),
    (SELECT 1 AS a, 4 AS b, NULL AS c),
    (SELECT 1 AS a, 5 AS b, 5 AS c)
)
```

> what value does it have over using LEAD

LEAD has more reach signature - `LEAD(<expr>[, <offset>[, <default_value>]])` - so if you just need first value you can short cut it to `FIRST_VALUE(<field_name>)` - I think this is the major practical difference

Comment: Also, I'm still processing a lot more data than I should have to. `NEST`ing all the values in my original window and then using `FIRST ... WITHIN` on the result will also pull the correct value, but that's still processing the whole window when it's unnecessary. And I was a bit rash at asking what value it has over `LEAD`, as a preceding window would be repetition to get the first value.

Comment: you still can vote on answer if it helped you anyhow as it actually answered your question I think :o)