# Return unique records in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

This is my table

| id | fruit | color | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | green | 10 |
| 2 | apple | red | 9.4 |
| 3 | apple | yellow | 6 |
| 4 | lemon | green | 8 |
| 5 | lemon | yellow | 5 |
| 6 | banana | yellow | 10 |
| 7 | banana | red | 6 |

It's sorted by score, I just need to get one record by fruit, I don't care about the color, however I need to show just the first value in color.

My desired outcome

| id | fruit | color | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | green | 10 |
| 4 | lemon | green | 8 |
| 6 | banana | yellow | 10 |

I can't use `SELECT DISTINCT` because If I'm returning the `color` column, it makes the entire record unique. I'm thinking of a script that once it finds a `fruit` that's already in the results, ignore the rest and show only the first one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the first not null value from a column of values in Big Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788958/how-to-get-the-first-not-null-value-from-a-column-of-values-in-big-query)  (It shows how to use the function `FIRST_VALUE()`)

Comment: @Luuk I think this is something I need, but I'm not sure how I can implement it, I'll test and research but is it possible for you to make a script with my example?

Comment: @DavidSalomon check the solution below and see if that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from [table_name]
qualify row_number() over(partition by fruit order by score desc) = 1
```

- assuming you are in need of first value, based on the highest score
- use the row_number(), it will produce 1,2,3 for each fruit and selecting qualify = 1 would return one row
- use qualify to directly filter the windows function results
- further you can read if you are looking for rank(), row_number() or dense_rank() from here [SQL RANK() versus ROW_NUMBER()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747327/sql-rank-versus-row-number)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rank()` and partition by fruit as a subquery...

```
select id, fruit, color, score
from (
  select id, fruit, color, score, 
  rank() over (partition by fruit order by score desc) as frank
  from my_data
  )z
where frank = 1
```

| id | fruit | color | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | green | 10 |
| 6 | banana | yellow | 10 |
| 4 | lemon | green | 8 |

If you have ties but only want one row each, then replace `rank()` with `row_number()`.

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick, as window functions tend to be slower onb big data

```
SELECT t1.id,   t1.fruit,   t1.color,   t1.score
FROM my_table t1 INNER JOIN (
SELECT MIN(id) min_id, fruit FROM my_table GROUP BY fruit) t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.min_id
```